# How to change the color text Android Bootstrap button

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, textcolor

I want to change the Text's color in a AndroidBootStrap Button.

I tried with `android:textColor="@color/Pink"` but the text still in black.

Peace of code including my bootstrap button in xml:

> ```
> <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
>                                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                                 bootstrapbutton:bb_size="xsmall"
>                                 android:text="Esporte"
>                                 android:textColor="@color/Pink"
>                                 bootstrapbutton:bb_icon_left="fa-check-circle-o"
>                                bootstrapbutton:bb_text_alignment="left"
>                                 bootstrapbutton:bb_text_gravity="left"
>                                 />
> ```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bootstrap for android** is a customised Library for having the similar look and feel of the default view of bootstrap for web. There is less scope for customisation. But if you really need to customise it then you can download the source of the Library project and add your customised properties in the BootstrapType constructor. Here is the source of the library of BootstrapButton. Just like the DEFAULT, PRIMARY you can add a CUSTOM property there you can add your color.

```
 private enum BootstrapType {
        DEFAULT("default", R.drawable.bbuton_default, R.drawable.bbuton_default_rounded, R.color.black),
        PRIMARY("primary", R.drawable.bbuton_primary, R.drawable.bbuton_primary_rounded, R.color.white),
        SUCCESS("success", R.drawable.bbuton_success, R.drawable.bbuton_success_rounded, R.color.white),
        INFO("info", R.drawable.bbuton_info, R.drawable.bbuton_info_rounded, R.color.white),
        WARNING("warning", R.drawable.bbuton_warning, R.drawable.bbuton_warning_rounded, R.color.white),
        DANGER("danger", R.drawable.bbuton_danger, R.drawable.bbuton_danger_rounded, R.color.white),
        INVERSE("inverse", R.drawable.bbuton_inverse, R.drawable.bbuton_inverse_rounded, R.color.white);

        private final String type;
        private final int normalBg;
        private final int roundedBg;
        private final int textColour;

        BootstrapType(String type, int normalBg, int roundedBg, int textColour) {
            this.type = type;
            this.normalBg = normalBg;
            this.roundedBg = roundedBg;
            this.textColour = textColour;
        }

        public static BootstrapType getBootstrapTypeFromString(String type) {
            for (BootstrapType value : BootstrapType.values()) {
                if (value.type.equals(type)) {
                    return value;
                }
            }
            return DEFAULT;
        }

        public int getTextColour() {
            return textColour;
        }

        public int getRoundedBg() {
            return roundedBg;
        }

        public int getNormalBg() {
            return normalBg;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you know any tutorial about how to add a library project on Android Studio. All what I have found is not working for me. Thank you

Comment: Yes, you can follow this link. The approved answer is perfectly explained.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio

Answer (score 1):

It can be done programmatically in the java file, but you would need to add an id to your button in the XML layout file first:

```
<com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
    android:id="@+id/register_button"
    ... />
```

Then, in the Java file:

```
BootstrapButton b = (BootstrapButton) findViewById(R.id.register_button);
b.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
```

Be aware that the method getColor(int) was deprecated in API 23, you can use it as

```
getColor(int, null)
```

if you will not support older API levels.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do it in the create()??

When you create the bottom for first time you can change the properties and then put the textColor in pink :)

Comment: It doesn't work because `.setTextColor();` method doesn't exist for an BootstrapButton ...